# Complex number conversion

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a little code in C++ and I'm having difficulties with the use of complex numbers. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::complex_literals;

double Diff (double pos,double kvector,double amp){
std::complex <double> E_complex_field=exp(-(1i)*kvector*pos);
std::complex <double> E_complexplus_field=exp(-(1i)*kvector*(pos+amp));
std::complex <double> Derivada=(E_complexplus_field-E_complex_field)/(double)amp;
return Derivada;
}

int main()
{   
    cout<<fixed <<setprecision(22);
    int N=100;
    double PI,lambda,k_vector,Epso,Eo,alfa_complex,x,paso,Fx,d;
    PI=acos(-1);    lambda=500*pow(10,-9);  k_vector=(1/(double)lambda);    Epso=1;     Eo=1;   paso=pow(10,-8);    d=pow(10,-4);
    complex<double> phase =(1i *k_vector*x);    complex<double> alfa=1.+(1i)*pow(10,-21);
    complex<double> E_field=Eo*exp(phase);      complex<double> Ec_field=conj(E_field);
                                alfa_complex=imag(alfa);
    x=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        Fx= (0.5)*real(Epso*pow(Eo,2)*alfa*E_field*Diff(x,k_vector,paso));
        x=x+d;
    }

}
```

The error in the code is the following:

```
Der_num.cpp:13:8: error: cannot convert ‘std::complex<double>’ to ‘double’ in return.
```

How can I obtain the value of Derivada?

Comment: **C++ is not C is not C++!** Use the correct tags

Comment: Apparently you want the function to return a `std::complex <double>`.

Comment: Yeah thats right, but it does not seem to work.. you know why? i mean it doesnt work either if i write std::complex <double> Derivada

Comment: Newlines are cheap — use them.  7 separate statements on a single line is not sensible; each variable should be its own declaration on its own line with its own initialization.  You also define and set but don't use `Fx`.  What's up?

Comment: If you want to return `std::complex<double>` from `Diff`, you write: `std::complex<double> Diff(double pos, double kvector, double amp)`, don't you?  If you want to return a single `double`, then you choose which part of `Derivada` you want to return — the real, the imaginary, the amplitude, something else?

Comment: I want to have the whole complete complex number back ( Derivada ), i understand why it doesnt work cause it isnt a double but i dont how to fix it.. maybe creating two functions like Derivada one giving me back the real part and the other the imaginary?

Comment: The function is called `Diff` and has to be declared to return a complex, as shown in JonathanLeffler's comment. If that didn't work, you need to edit the question to show the exact code you tried, along with the error messages that you got.

Comment: Thank you all, it works!